# "Battery" and "Battery", why are they called the same?

Tags: meaning, etymology, nouns

[This post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6467/how-is-an-assault-different-from-battery-in-everyday-english/6477#6477) made an interesting point about what would be understood when the word battery is used.

> In the U.S. at least, the word battery
>   is so rarely used outside the legal
>   phrase assault and battery  that a
>   listener would be pretty much
>   guaranteed to assume it meant an
>   electrical battery unless it was
>   specifically disambiguated by context.

This prompted me to see if there is a difference in the etymology of each words. According to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/battery), they both have the same origin, the Old French *baterie*, which means "the action of beating". So this prompted many questions: How did the meaning of the word evolve in one case to "A device that produces electricity by a chemical reaction between two substances."? When was it first used as such? Or is there a mistake in Wiktionary concerning the etymology of *electrical battery*?

Comment: Consider an OIL BATTERY - where the cleaning and treating of Heavy Oil occurs. HOW is that connected?

Comment: When I read this I thought of the row of guns on a battleship.

Comment: [Another curious use of 'battery', in modern construction industry](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/90314/why-is-it-battery-in-battery-limit-a-construction-industry-term)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Etymonline has [this](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=battery&searchmode=none):

> Meaning shifted in M.Fr. from "bombardment" ("heavy blows" upon city walls or fortresses) to "unit of artillery" (a sense recorded in English from 1550s). Extension to "electrical cell" (1748, first used by Ben Franklin) is perhaps via notion of "discharges" of electricity.

Wikipedia drops the "perhaps" and [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_%28electricity%29#History):

> The usage of "battery" to describe electrical devices dates to Benjamin Franklin, who in 1748 described multiple Leyden jars (early electrical capacitors) by analogy to a battery of cannons.<sup>[[5]](http://inventors.about.com/library/inventors/blbattery.htm)</sup>

That last link goes to About.com, where we read:

> - 1748 - Benjamin Franklin first coined the term "battery" to describe an array of charged glass plates.

Comment: Note that originally an electrical battery was made up of multiple cells: my father used to observe this distinction, and was known to object to referring to a single cell as a "battery".

Comment: That's the link between a line of cannon and a line of cells making up a battery. Is the link between assault+battery and a cannon battery obvious?

Comment: I wonder if the habit of referring to a pitcher-catcher combination in baseball as the battery is also related to this sense of "a set"

Comment: @KateGregory [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_(baseball))

Comment: There are still a few of us old-timers around who object (very mildly) to referring to, say, a "C cell" as a "battery".

Comment: This answer leaves an impression that the explanations offered by Etymonline and Wikipedia are similar. They are in fact quite different: the first one claims that the use of the word is 'perhaps' due to the 'discharges' of electricity being somehow similar to bombardment, while the second is that the multiplicity of the cells in a battery is analogous to the multiplicity of cannons in a battery of cannons. It should be noted that the comments by Colin Fine and Hot Licks both assume that the second explanation is the correct one and, perhaps rightly, ignore the first one.

Answer (score 12):

The word `batterie` in French (and `batteria` in Italian) identify a sequence of identical objects. E.g. a `batterie of cannons` or a `batterie of electrical cells`.

The word came from the ancient Greek `baktérion` that means `stick`.

The "missing link" is the french verb `battre`. This verb is used to refer to hunting technique of [battue](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/battue). Imagine a sequence of men, each one with his stick, that walk aligned to pursuit the hunted animal and you'll understand the etymology of the word `batterie`.

It is not easy to track all the passage in the evolution of these words because them jumped forth and back from a language to another.

Comment: Do you have evidence for your "missing link"? I had supposed that, as at etymonline, the transfer was via artillery rather than via hunting.

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear in my answer, I agree with you. IMHO, the word "born" in hunting, then it extended to other fields (such as artillery or housewares) and, only in modern days, it migrated from artillery to "electrical cell".

Comment: While I was searching for my old sources on the subject, I found a on [cnrtl](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/batterie) an alternate ipothesis: `1294 « ensemble des ustensiles en métal battu dont on se sert pour la cuisine » (Peage de Dijon, B.N. 1. 9873, fo 23 vo, Ibid. : Trousseaux de la batherie)`

Comment: It is correct that the English word comes from French battre "to beat". This comes from Latin battuere, and has nothing to do with Greek bakterion "staff". Where did you find that nonsense?